# How to add Custom CSS colors to Input color of Material UI Text Field component

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

interface IProps {
  type: string;
  label: string;
  color:
    | "error"
    | "primary"
    | "secondary"
    | "info"
    | "success"
    | "warning"
    | undefined;
}

const Input: FunctionComponent<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <TextField
        required
        id="outlined-password-input"
        label={props.label}
        type={props.type}
        color={props.color}
        autoComplete="current-password"
        style={{ width: "50vw" }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

How to add Theme colors to outlines and font color of Textfield. On a dark background, it shows dark text.

How to use global styles in Typescript, it shows an error when using theme

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing my research for about an hour and I can't get it to work. The only way I've found is to cast the value as primary, which of course isn't the best thing to do. But it's the only solution I've found.

In your case:

```
<TextField
    {...}
    color={(myCustomColor as 'primary')}
  />
```